# xPath normalize space Example

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, scrapy, normalize-space

The following line is a scrapy selector. How would I apply `normalize-space()` to this?

```
rows.xpath("//table[@id='PlaceHolderMain']/tbody/tr/td[1]/span/text()").get()
```

Comment: `normalize-space()` for which text? Update the question with the relevant text based HTML.

Comment: the text is in the span element

Comment: //table[@id='PlaceHolderMain_gvUnitShippingInfo']/tbody/tr[position() >1]/td[1]/span/text()

Answer (score 0):

To use the text **jim Burns** through `normalize-space()` you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
ows.xpath("//table[@id='PlaceHolderMain']/tbody/tr/td[1]/span[normalize-space()='jim Burns']").get()
```

Comment: thanks. that looks like the answers i've seen. thing is.. i'm using the xpath statement to scrape a webpage. i don't know what the text is going to be. its whatever is in the span element